# How to choose target package when promoting from OSS Jfrog to bintray?

Tags: artifactory, bintray

I'm using Travis(https://travis-ci.org/Orange-OpenSource/elpaaso-dbaas-wsdl) to build my maven project. I'm able to deploy artifacts and [buildInfo](https://oss.jfrog.org/webapp/#/builds/elpaaso-dbaas-wsdl) to OSS JFrog and to promote snapshot to bintray. But my artifact is pushed into the wrong package.

Expected to be here: bintray.com/elpaaso/maven/elpaaso-dbaas-wsdl/view

But it's here : bintray.com/elpaaso/maven/elpaaso-plugins-management/1.63.12/view#files

I'm using curl to promote to bintray

curl --silent -X POST -u user:password http ://oss.jfrog.org/api/plugins/build/promote/snapshotsToBintray/elpaaso-dbaas-wsdl/12

How to choose target package when promoting from OSS Jfrog to bintray ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [in the user guide](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Snapshots+to+oss.jfrog.org#DeployingSnapshotstooss.jfrog.org-PromotingaBuildUsingRESTAPI), the REST API call includes build name and build number as a part of the URI (not repo name and id as in your example).

Bintray details (the repo and the package) are associated with maven groupId that you provided during the request for inclusion of the package to jcenter.

Comment: My bad for REST call, I've updated it with real value instead of incorrect var name... And I missed registration to jcenter on bintray. So it is not possible to target a specific "Bintray package" when promoting from OSS JFrog. It is done automatically using request for inclusion info.

Comment: You couldn't miss the registration, that's how the account in OJO is created. Anyhow, please email to support@bintray.com, they will fix the metadata to associate the maven groupID to Bintray package.

Comment: Someboy else, from the our org, registered another component with same groupId. So I was able to deploy snapshot to OSS JFrog. Anyway, thanks, and sorry for that.